# How can I link executable with dylib in Mac OS X command line?

Tags: c++, macos, linker-errors, clang++, dylib

I'm trying to figure out how to compile things on command line without a and ide. This is my first time building a project using command line. And, I get stomped on linking dependencies on a simple project.

I have this tree structure:

```
.
├── include
...
...
├── lib
│   ├── libopencv_calib3d.3.3.1.dylib
│   ├── libopencv_core.3.3.1.dylib
│   ├── libopencv_cudev.3.3.1.dylib
│   ├── libopencv_features2d.3.3.1.dylib
│   ├── libopencv_flann.3.3.1.dylib
│   ├── libopencv_highgui.3.3.1.dylib
│   ├── libopencv_imgcodecs.3.3.1.dylib
│   ├── libopencv_imgproc.3.3.1.dylib
│   ├── libopencv_videoio.3.3.1.dylib
│   ├── libopencv_ximgproc.3.3.1\ 2.dylib
│   └── libopencv_ximgproc.3.3.1.dylib
├── resources
│   ├── giraffe.jpg
│   ├── golden-retriver-puppy.jpg
│   ├── kangaroo.jpg
│   └── kitty.jpeg
└── sources
    └── main.cpp
```

and I have this code in the main:

```
#include "opencv2/ximgproc/segmentation.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

static void help() {
    std::cout << std::endl <<
    "Usage:" << std::endl <<
    "./ssearch input_image (f|q)" << std::endl <<
    "f=fast, q=quality" << std::endl <<
    "Use l to display less rects, m to display more rects, q to quit" << std::endl;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
    // If image path and f/q is not passed as command
    // line arguments, quit and display help message
    if (argc < 3) {
        help();
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and in my mac terminal I built it with this command:

```
clang++ sources/main.cpp -o a -I./include -L./lib -lopencv_core.3.3.1 -lopencv_ximgproc.3.3.1 -lopencv_highgui.3.3.1 -lopencv_imgproc.3.3.1 -lopencv_imgcodecs.3.3.1
```

and it doesn't give me any errors.

but when I run `~$ ./a`

I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libopencv_core.3.3.dylib
  Referenced from: 
  /Users/lgdelacruz/Documents/GSoC/project/objectdetection/./a
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I've been messing with these for days, and I can't seem to figure it out. How does the executable find the things to link to when it needs those definitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dynamically linking libraries to compile your code, which needs to tell the system where to find the libraries both **compile time** and **run time**.

Right now, you are only telling the compiler to compile from libraries in the path specified by -L, but not telling the system where to find the libraries when executing it.

You probably need this:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

where `./lib` indicates where your libraries are.